# Angular 6 router not working on chrome/IE

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot, angular6

I am using angular 6 to redirect the user. When login success the user redirect to the home page. The same code works perfectly on Firefox(version 52.8.1) but chrome is not redirected to the child url.

My routing code is :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard/home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
      {path: 'InfoManage', component: InfoManageComponent},
      {path: 'home',component: HomeComponent}
    ]
  },
  // All Other Routes Goto Login *****************************************/
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/login'}
];
```

When  blank("") url comes firefox redirect to the **/dashboard/home** but chrome redirect to the **/dashboard** only. Is this the angular bug or am I missing something?

Comment: it does indeed look like a bug, if i were you have the redirect to `dashboard` and within the dashboard route, have a redirect to home when no route after dashboard is specified

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem about priority of routes and not about with Chrome.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
      {path: '',component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'InfoManage', component: InfoManageComponent}
    ]
  },
  // All Other Routes Goto Login *****************************************/
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/login'}
];
```

For empty '' routes try to redirect directly 'dashboard' and than handle case. I hope it works.